# Adding data to list (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, list, nullpointerexception

I am new in this all,and I have problem with adding data to list.

For example I declare it like :

```
List<ColorL> Color   = new List<ColorL>();
```

Whero ColorL is

```
 public class ColorL
    {
        public int Color_No { get; set; }
        public string Color_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I try:

```
Color[i].Color_No  = Convert.ToInt32(txtColorCode.Text);
```

Where i is some number.

Now i get NullReferenceException for this problem.

I think that this wold work for reading data, but I am not sure how to make insert.

Thanks

Comment: how do you instantiate Vehicle?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake , while i type, i change this..

Comment: If you never add a ColorL to the list, Color[i] will be null. Did you call Color.Add(new ColorL()); ???

Answer (score 0):

From error you have I can tell that you have `null` in `i` index of your `Color` list. Assign `ColorL` instance to index `i` of list. E.g. filling of list may look like

```
List<ColorL> Color = new List<ColorL>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   Color.Add(new ColorL());
```

That will create 10 new instances of `ColorL` and add them to list. Thus you will be able reference them by indexes 0..9.

Less probable reason is that your `txtColorCode` text box is not instantiated.